# Issues in database connection in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been creating registration form using php.

And my database and table look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XQ8b.jpg

This is the database connection query:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/fg_membersite.php");

$fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();

//Provide your site name here

//Provide the email address where you want to get notifications
$fgmembersite->SetAdminEmail('rajaselva.csc@gmail.com');

//Provide your database login details here:
//hostname, user name, password, database name and table name
//note that the script will create the table (for example, fgusers in this case)
//by itself on submitting register.php for the first time
$fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                      /*username*/'root',
                      /*password*/'',
                      /*database name*/'employee',
                      /*table name*/'employee-reg');

//For better security. Get a random string from this link: http://tinyurl.com/randstr
// and put it here
$fgmembersite->SetRandomKey('qSRcVS6DrTzrPvr');

?>
```

After entering the input details, it shows like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD6IQ.jpg

May I know, what is my mistake, how can I fix this.

Can anybody help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: The provided code does not create any tables.

Comment: Paste the error you're getting *here* as text. Why are you requiring us to view a tiny image on an external site?

Comment: this is my error: Error creating the table 
query was
Create Table employee-reg (id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,phone_number VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,confirmcode VARCHAR(32) ,PRIMARY KEY ( id_user ))
mysqlerror:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-reg (id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,email V' at line 1

Comment: You are trying to add a data on `confirmcode` which is not exists in `employeetable`.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: now it shows, Failed sending registration confirmation email.

Comment: So your data get stored in your table right?

Comment: So How you are sending an email? update your question with email code.

Comment: my class.phpmailer.php file is huge.. so can i update?

Comment: No you don't need to update it. Now the issue is only with your email you can post separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your table name you should not user minus(-) sign in your table name. If you really need to use it then enclose it with back-ticks (`). See the Example Below:

CREATE TABLE `employee-reg` (id int, name varchar( 255 )); //Works Well

CREATE TABLE employee-reg (id int, name varchar( 255 )); //Will Not Work and gives error

**Error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-reg (id int, name varchar( 255 ))' at line 1

Quite Similar to your error. So either remove minus(-) sign or use back-ticks(`).

Comment: but i have i got another one issue

Comment: for that I think you can create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Add back tick (``) on the employee-reg table name. Hope that will work

```
$fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                      /*username*/'root',
                      /*password*/'',
                      /*database name*/'employee',
                      /*table name*/'`employee-reg`');
```